# Unexplained high HDD activity on Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: server, disk-management

Recently installed Ubuntu Server 22.04 running LAMP stack and EspoCRM application. Unfortunately pretty rusty on the troubleshooting side of systems admin. Applications are working fine but my HDD is getting hammered with excessive activity.

Have tried starting/stopping applications to see which might be the culprit. Have been unsuccessful in isolating the offending service. Have checked /var/logs and don't see anything particularly unusual. Got a UFW block error msg on a cron job being initiated by EspoCRM. Disabled cron and HDD is still getting hammered.

Would appreciate some help in trying to track this thing down.

System spec's:

As-built Intel based server w 2 3TB WD SATA HDDs
Ubuntu server 22.04, did generic install. no customization, no LVM. Ext4 /dev/sda primary
UFW enabled
LAMP stack running EspoCRM.
Running SSH via custom port
No monitoring software

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Is there anything in `/var/log/syslog` that might point to the issue? Checking the Apache logs may also help, as unreasonably large access/error logs may point to DDOS-like issues 

Comment: Run atop as root, wait 10s for startup, put it in Disk mode (press 'd'), see what process is hammering your disk.